# Find the limit of $\lim\limits_{(x,y,z) \rightarrow (1,2,-3)} \arctan \frac{x + z}{y}$ and prove that your result is correct.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Find the limit and prove that your result is correct.

$$\lim _{(x,y,z) \rightarrow (1,2,-3)} \arctan \frac{x + z}{y}.$$

**My trial:**

I found the limit by direct substitution and it was $7 \pi/8,$ because we are in the forth quadrant ..... am I correct? but now I do not know how to prove this using $\epsilon - \delta$ definition, the answer was given that $\delta = \frac{-2 \epsilon}{ 3 - \epsilon},$ but I do not know how ..... could anyone clarify this for me please?

Comment: Hint: Is your function continuous around $(1,2,-3)$?

Comment: Hint: $|\arctan \, x -\arctan\, y| \leq |x-y|$.

Comment: The $\delta $ you have mentioned is a negative number!.

Comment: I do not know this is the delta given while the  problem  was solved in the class (may be the negative in the numerator does not exist )@KaviRamaMurthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\frac {x+z} y +1| \leq \frac {|x-1|+|y-2|+|z+3|} {|y|}<\frac {3 \delta} {2-\delta}$ if $|(x,y,z)-(1,2-3)| <\delta$. Now use my comment above. Can you complete the argument now?

Comment: how is $2 - |y| > 2 - \delta$?

Comment: @hopefully There was a typo. The denominator was supposed to be $|y|$.

Comment: Thank you Kavi :)

Comment: so $\delta = 2\epsilon / (3 + \epsilon)$ ...... correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Could you please look at this question if you have time https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3132899/a-difficulty-in-understanding-theorem-10-6-7-in-petrovic-n-dimensional-intermed

Answer (score 1):

$\tan^{-1}x$ is continuous around $-1$.

Hence $\lim_{(x,y,z)\to (1,2,-3)}\tan^{-1}\frac{x+y}z=\tan ^{-1}\frac{1+(-3)}2=\tan^{-1}(-1)=-\frac{\pi}4$.